# Hystrix deployment in an EE container with bulkhead enabled

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly-10, hystrix

The EE spec does not encourage the creation of threads in a container. But for Hystrix to implement the bulkhead pattern for thread isolation, it needs to create new threads. So my question is, if an application makes remote calls wrapped with Hystrix, and that application is deployed in an EE container such as wildfly, and Hystrix is configured with thread pool enabled for the bulkhead pattern, does this not cause conflicts on the container with regards to new threads creation?

Answer (score 0):

We induced this error below, by setting the maximumSize to be less that the coreSize.

17:52:37,412 ERROR [com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixConcurrencyStrategy] (EE-ManagedExecutorService-default-Thread-1) Hystrix ThreadPool configuration at startup for : TEST_THREAD_POOL is trying to set coreSize = 15 and maximumSize = 10.  Maximum size will be set to 15, the coreSize value, since it must be equal to or greater than the coreSize value

Hystrix bumbs up the maximumSize to be the same as the coreSize.

But the most important piece of information is that behind the scenes, Hystrix uses EE-ManagedExecutorService, which is what we want.